# Form validates before submit

Tags: php, forms, validation

Just a quick one, i can't seem to spot and was hoping some one else could spot my mistake, i have a some string validation code written in PHP and the problem i am having is that the form seems to validate the "customerfname" field as soon as it is opened not when the submit button is hit, as soon as the form is opened the error "Please enter your first name" is displayed even before the submit button is pressed. Could anyone spot my mistake?

```
<?php

$flag = false;
$badchar = "";
$string = $_POST["customerfname"];
$string = trim($string);
$length = strlen($string);
$strmsg = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if ($length == 0) {
        $strmsg = '<span class="error"> Please enter your first name</span>';
        $flag = true;
        $valid = false;}
    else if ($length > 30) {
        $strmsg = '<span class="error"> Can not enter more than 30 characters</span>';
        $flag = true;
        $valid = false;
        }
else{
    for ($i=0; $i<$length;$i++){
        $c = strtolower(substr($string, $i, 1));
        if (strpos("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-", $c) === false){
             $badchar .=$c;
             $flag = true;
             $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if ($flag) {
        $strmsg = '<span class="error"> The field contained the following invalid characters: '.$badchar.'</span>';}
    }
    if (!$flag) {
        $valid = true;
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="custinfo">

<td><label for="customerfname">Customer First Name: </label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50/><?php echo $strmsg; ?></td>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data"/>&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />

</form>
```

Comment: Learn regex, you won't regret it.

Comment: Tried and didn't have the problem... I noticed that no $_POST['submit'] is sent, though, so didn't even enter the validation code.

Comment: you dont have a submit button?

Comment: You should move everything from line 5 to 8 under your isset($_POST['submit'])

Comment: You are missing a submit button with "submit" name

Comment: Sorry! i have a submit button on my actual form i just forgot to add it in here, i have added it now.

Comment: @evuez i just put the whole section of PHP between $_POST['submit'] but still the same problem.

Comment: @francis see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$flag = false;
$badchar = "";
$strmsg = "";
if(isset($_POST['customerfname']))
{
$string = $_POST["customerfname"];
$string = trim($string);
$length = strlen($string);
}
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if ($length == 0) {
$strmsg = '<span class="error"> Please enter your first name</span>';
$flag = true;
$valid = false;}
else if ($length > 30) {
$strmsg = '<span class="error"> Can not enter more than 30 characters</span>';
$flag = true;
$valid = false;}
else {
for ($i=0; $i<$length;$i++){
    $c = strtolower(substr($string, $i, 1));
    if (strpos("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-", $c) === false){
        $badchar .=$c;
        $flag = true;
        $valid = false;
    }
}
if ($flag) {
    $strmsg = '<span class="error"> The field contained the following invalid characters: '.$badchar.'</span>';}
}
if (!$flag) {
    $valid = true;}
    var_dump($valid);
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="" id="custinfo">

<td><label for="customerfname">Customer First Name: </label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50/><?php echo $strmsg; ?></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>

</form>
```

Comment: How should i written it then?

Comment: I vardumped $valid if the $_POST meets your requirements

Comment: and to show your comment when it does not you should write this:
<?php if(isset($strmsg)) { echo $strmsg; } ?>

Comment: copy the entire code and add this after the input  <?php if(isset($strmsg)) { echo $strmsg; } ?> im sure it works

Comment: Copied the exact code and added the code to display my comment as well but still the same problem, thank you for the tips though.

Comment: how do i check the vardump?

Comment: it seems to be working when everyone else tries my original code as well, just not for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a submit button with "submit" as name, and move all the lines regarding the POST request under your `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))`

Here is a working (there is a lot more to improve, but that's a beginning) version of your code:

```
<?php

$flag = false;
$badchar = "";
$strmsg = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $string = (isset($_POST["customerfname"])) ? $_POST["customerfname"] : ''; // if customerfname wasn't sent, $string will be empty
    $string = trim($string);
    $length = strlen($string);

    if ($length == 0) {
        $strmsg = '<span class="error"> Please enter your first name</span>';
        $flag = true;
        $valid = false;
    }
    else if ($length > 30) {
        $strmsg = '<span class="error"> Can not enter more than 30 characters</span>';
        $flag = true;
        $valid = false;
    }
    else {
        for ($i=0; $i<$length;$i++) {
                $c = strtolower(substr($string, $i, 1));
                if (strpos("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-", $c) === false) {
                    $badchar .=$c;
                    $flag = true;
                    $valid = false;
                }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            $strmsg = '<span class="error"> The field contained the following invalid characters: '.$badchar.'</span>';
        }
    }
    if (!$flag) {
        $valid = true;
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="custinfo">

<td><label for="customerfname">Customer First Name: </label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50/><?php echo $strmsg; ?></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>

</form>
```

Comment: I do have a submit button with the name "submit" and currently have the whole section of PHP code under (isset($_POST["submit"])) but i tried your method anyway still with no luck.

Comment: Try "if (empty($string))" instead of "if ($length == 0)". btw what is your version of PHP?